# Fit image inside dynamically created div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having issues in fitting `student.jpg` inside a DIV.

Requirement: `galleryWrap` is inside `logOuterWrap`. I need to fit `student.jpg` inside `galleryWrap`.

jQuery:

```
galleryID++;
var logOuterWrap = $("<div/>",{class: "galleryBox", id: "main"+galleryID }).appendTo("#galleryContainer")
var galleryWrap = $("<div/>",{class: "galleryInner", id: "gallery"+galleryID }).appendTo(logOuterWrap)

galleryWrap.append(
            $("#gallery"+galleryID).html("<img src='img/student.jpg'/>"),"<br />");
```

CSS:

```
#galleryContainer{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #fff;
}
.galleryBox{
    background-color: #00ff00;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: `{class: "galleryBox"` may break in IE. Enclose `'class'` or use `.addClass()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you end up with this HTML structure

```
<div id="galleryContainer">
    <div class="galleryBox">
        <div class="galleryInner">
            <img src="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So this CSS would fit the image without distorting proportions

```
.galleryInner img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/wwbekuqk/

If you also want to center align the image horizontally and vertically:

```
.galleryBox{
    background-color: #00ff00;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
}

.galleryInner img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/wwbekuqk/1/

Comment: thanks. In your second example: Rather than placing the images one below the other how can I position the images side by side?

Comment: `<div>` is a block element, you might want to find out what `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a Img tag, set the `galleryWrap` background as the image and set the `background-size:cover`

Comment: Currently this is a comment. Can you show as an answer using code that OP can apply directly?